# Some questions related the autocompletion of the fish shell

Tags: shell, fish

When typing the beginning of a command in the fish shell the most recent (or frequently?) possible completion of the command is visible in dark grey.

Say I type:

```
fish
```

in dark grey: `_config` is appended.

at this time it is not yet evident, what I'm about to do. So the `TAB` key shows me all possible completions of '`fish`'

I can keep on typing characters, until it's clear what I want. E.g: `_con`

Now there is only one option to which this could be completed. So I can hit the tab key to see fish_config. However: this was not indicated somehow. In other words: After typing fish_con nothing really tells me that I don't have to keep on typing. Is this the case? Wouldn't this be extremely helpful?

Second question: What is the actual sense of the grey characters? I'd only understand their purpose if there was a way to accept this propose. After typing `f`, I'd expect a key combination that immediately fully completes to the propose in grey: `fish_config`.

Even better would be the option let the grey letters cycle through all options, or possible completions based on the history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The characters to the right of the cursor are called the autosuggestion. They are gray to indicate that they are not actually part of the command, just a suggested completion of what you've typed so far.

> So I can hit the tab key to see fish_config. However: this was not indicated somehow. In other words: After typing fish_con nothing really tells me that I don't have to keep on typing

This sounds like you have an idea for an indication when the partial command is a unique prefix of another command. I am not sure what UI you have in mind - what would the indication look like? Please feel welcome to [open an issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues) with your UI ideas.

However if your command is unique, the autosuggestion will always contain it.

> Second question: What is the actual sense of the grey characters? I'd only understand their purpose if there was a way to accept this propose. After typing f, I'd expect a key combination that immediately fully completes to the propose in grey: fish_config.

You can accept the autosuggestion by hitting right arrow or control-F. Tab shows you all possible completions, and up arrow lets you cycle through matching history.

You may want to read the fish tutorial, which covers autosuggestions here: http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_autosuggestions